# Html searchable list that redirects to a website depending on the selected option

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, hyperlink, datalist

Is it possible to make the options redirect to a website url?

```html
<input list="browsers">

<datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Internet Explorer">
  <option value="Firefox">
  <option value="Chrome">
  <option value="Opera">
  <option value="Safari">
</datalist>
```

Basically how would i combine the code above and the code below?

```html
 <a href="https://www.google.com/">Google</a>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/kokb207o/
You can use Javascript to accomplish this feat, by changing the href of your  element as follows:

HTML

```
<select id="browsers" onblur='changeHref()'>
  <option value="google">Google</option>
  <option value="youtube">Youtube</option>
  <option value="facebook">Facebook</option>
  <option value="instagram">Instagram</option>
  <option value="twitter">Twitter</option>
</select>
<a href='javascript: void(0)' id='url' target='_blank'>Click Me!</a>
```

Javascript

```
function changeHref() {
  document.getElementById('url').href = 'http://www.' + document.getElementById('browsers').value + '.com';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet. For some reason websites like google.com is not redirecting due to security reasons. But first link working

```js
function redirect(goto) {
  if (goto != '') {
    window.location = goto;
  }
}

var selectEl = document.getElementById('redirectSelect');

selectEl.onchange = function() {
  var goto = this.value;
  redirect(goto);

};
```

```html
<select id="redirectSelect">
    <option value="">Please select</option>
    <option value="https://www.codeconquest.com/what-is-coding/
">Code Conquest</option>
    <option value="https://www.google.com">Google</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Is it possible to use with datalist?